# GDAL not properly installed. Missmatch of paths or similar

Tags: python, gdal

I am not sure if everything is the same problem or not, but I will describe as good as I can what is going on.

In my old laptop I had QGIS installed, and when I wanted to use gdal standalone from python, I was building from source gdal2.3 and everything was working.

In my new laptop (and I freshed installed ubuntu 18.04 twice), everything has been problems. QGIS 2.18 and 3.2 don't work for a problem with libpng. (Not related I think, but something that had never happened)

Now if I try to execute some code that includes `ReadAsArray` in Pycharm I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal_array'`.

I purged everything related with gdal (QGIS, gdal from pip, deleted the folder where I did `make`) and I tried to build from source again, this time doing `./configure --with-python=python3` (because i noticed that it was being installed over python2).

The most strange thing comes now: If I open a python console (which uses `/usr/bin/python3.6`, the same interpreter than pycharm) I can do `from osgeo import gdal`, but i can't import it in the script.

EDIT:

In console i can import gdal, but if I try `ReadAsArray` it says it can't import `gdalnumeric`

EDIT2:

I recompiled gdal using `--prefix=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and added that path, but still not working...

I never had so much problems and I'm really too lost right now.

Comment: it looks like a misconfiguration of PYTHONPATH in pycharm, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198319/how-to-configure-custom-pythonpath-with-vm-and-pycharm

Comment: I though so also at the beginning, and I exported the path after gdal compile (it actually tells you to do so). So my interpreter paths already include `/usr/lib/python3.6` and `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

Comment: I just realized that gdal is installed under `/home/name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/` but it does not let me that folder to the paths, it says it doesnt exist